# Guests for events in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm coding a little project on Rails but I'm a bit stuck approaching a point of it.

It's an event organising platform where registered users can create their own events (like social networks' events) and then invite people from outside of the platform without having them register on it. I'm currently managing registered users through Devise and the events part is also done, so by now users can register, sign in/out... and create events.

My doubt comes when approaching the guest part. I've tried creating a new model (guest) and adding the devise functionality to it like i did with the users but I couldn't get it to work properly.

I'd like users to be able to invite guests to their events through email and the platform would generate an invitation code for them so they can login into that specific event with their combination of email and invitation code so they can check the event's info and be able to tell the host if they're attending to the event or not.

As I've modeled on my Entity-Relation, guests would be a weak entity, as they fully depend of the event, so the guest model itself can include the attendance info.

So my question is, what should be the RoR way to approach this? Can I use Devise for this matter or is there any other easier way?

Comment: It sounds to me like guests are the same as users. Why not just create a new user (the guest) when the guest accepts the invite?

Comment: @Trigork I think i answered your question, fell free to comment if you need some help.

Comment: In an older implementation of this problem that I made years ago in PHP, users and guests were the same, but with different roles. As I stated below, I want to keep the guests as dependant as possible to the event, and I think that means a different model.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to go about this is to have a Guest model like you tried:

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Then your User and Event model would look like:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  # the owner of the event
  belongs_to :user
  # an event has 0..n guests coming to it
  has_many :guests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :saved_users, through: :guests, source: :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # a user has 0..n created events
  has_many :events
  # a user has many guests for those created events
  has_many :guests, dependent: :destroy

  # a user has 0 to n saved guests through the guests table
  has_many :saved_guests, through: :guests, source: :event

  # the rest of the Devise configuration code goes here ...
  # ...
end
```

I don't know about you but I prefer to do these models manually instead of the built in methods such that you really get some neat practice handling associations and relationships between models, see the official guide for more info on through, has many, etc:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

The `dependent: :destroy` clause is to ensure the guest gets deleted when you call destroy on the owner of the event, or the event itself.

Comment: The question here is, how would you log the gusts into the events and such?

Comment: Well in your controller for that it would just be 'current_user.guests.create(user: user)', or something similar depending on where you are saving the guests.

Comment: I was talking about something similar to the functionality that Devise provides (login, logout, sessions, etc) but for the guests so they can login into the event, see it's info and tell if they're attending or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Devise, you can just add the [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) gem. This gem will allow your logged in users to invite someone.

The gem will generate an invitation token, and customizable views for `invited users`.

When an `invited user` become a `real user` (when he accept the invitation and register), he'll be able to accept the event invitation.

I don't think you really need a `Guest` model here.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the guests to necessarily register into the platform. I want to keep them dependent to the event so their information stays as anonymous to the platform as it can. This way if the event gets deleted, their information goes away too.